# Printf erases the screen (using the MoSync library)

Tags: c++, mosync

I have some simple code that looks like this:

```
printf("Press zero or back to exit\n");
maSetColor(0x0055ff);
maFillRect(10,10,100,100);
maUpdateScreen();
```

This runs, but when it's like this:

```
maSetColor(0x0055ff);
maFillRect(10,10,100,100);
maUpdateScreen();
printf("Press zero or back to exit\n");
```

`printf` erases the screen.

Why is this? Is this a normal property of `printf()`? Is there a different print function I should use to print on top of everything, instead of erasing everything? I know I can use MoSync's `MaDrawText()` instead, but I was wondering if there was a print function that would also work.

Comment: How do you know it's the `printf` that erases the screen? I'm not familiar with mosync, but it looks like it's similar to curses or ncurses; if so, mixing it with direct writes to `stdout` like `printf` is probably a bad idea. Why don't you want to use `MaDrawText()`?

Comment: That's what I'm using. I just don't know why `printf` erases the screen. I wasn't sure if this was normal for various C++ libraries.

Comment: It's not normal for `printf` to erase the screen, but I suppose mosync might be putting the screen into some mode where normal characters are interpreted differently. I'd try adding something like a `sleep(5)` call just before the `printf` to make sure that it's the `printf` that's doing it. It would also help to know what environment you're running in (OS, terminal emulator, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior, [`printf()`](http://www.mosync.com/files/imports/doxygen/latest/html/conprint_8h.html#a55f3d956bb2ba20b5059e9e25484a47f) will display text in a seperate screen. The alternative is [`maDrawText(int left, int top, const char* str);`](http://www.mosync.com/files/imports/doxygen/latest/html/maapi_8h.html#ade0ec22d41fb3b366a1c4092b6c21721) which will allow you to draw the text in the paint area.

Your code could look like:

```
//Draw the Rectangle
maSetColor(0x0055ff);
maFillRect(10,10,100,100);

//Draw the text
maSetColor(0xffffff);
maDrawText(10,10,"Press zero or back to exit");

//Update the screen to reflect changes
maUpdateScreen();
```

Your first example works because you are calling the function before you update the screen and hence printf() will not draw on top of your current drawing.